# Cannot open include file: No such file or directory, but it exists in Additional Include Directory

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, boost, visual-studio-2022, vcpkg

When trying to build a C++ project in Visual Studio 2022 I get:

> Cannot open include file: 'boost/asio.hpp': No such file or directory

Include line causing error:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
```

But I **did** include the path to this file through Additional Include Directories already.

[image]

In my user's desktop directory `x64-windows\include` folder contains `boost` folder, which contains the included `asio.hpp` file. It also contains `asio` folder.

Edit: Changing `<boost/asio.hpp>` to `"boost/asio.hpp"` doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed it for me:

```
.\\vcpkg.exe integrate install
```

it returned:

```
Applied user-wide integration for this vcpkg root.

All MSBuild C++ projects can now #include any installed libraries.
Linking will be handled automatically.
Installing new libraries will make them instantly available.
```

Now the project compiles without any problem.